# Spring Batch - code is running within every 1 to 3 seconds, I set that run after every 10 sec

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, scheduled-tasks

@Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")
    public String importCsvToDb(){
        String response = null;
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addLong("startAt", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters(); 
        try {
            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
            response = "Data Imported to Customer Table from customers.csv file";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

I am working on spring batch where I put my job run time in every 10 seconds but its running within 1 to 3 seconds at every turn.